# Changing the same thing over an over againg PHP

Tags: php

So I have some simple PHP files about 80 of them, and I want to change the same thing in all of them. Is there any tool/framework that can help me with it? The changes are also very simple, but I don't want to just copy-paste it.

Comment: Can't your IDE help using the `Refactor` or the usual search and replace option ?

Comment: How about using Notepad++ and do a "Find in files" and for each result, search & replace?

Comment: Eclipse search and replace in files/folder, text editors or write your own script & regex if its complicated.

Comment: I don't want to use copy paste.

Comment: @DonCallisto I have Win XP, what difference does it make?

Comment: @user2786496 If you had a unix-based system you could use `sed` command ...

Comment: Could you give an example of that simple change? If they are one-liners then you could iterate through a list of files, read file contents into string, use str_replace and overwrite the file.

Answer (score 0):

Use an application like editpad pro or notepad++ that has the ability to alter multiple files at the same time, via regex or simple copy + replace.

I've done it before using editpad pro when I had to alter *nix DNS entries, it did 278 in 2 minutes.

Comment: as I said, I DON'T WANT to use copy/paste, I am looking for a tool

Comment: And as I wrote, you wouldn't need too. Editpad Pro and Notepad++ both have a Copy and Replace function built in. Technically I should have written "Search and replace across multiple documents" =)

Answer (score 0):

Using command line you can do it. In zend framework for example, you can comment alla require_once in the library using this command line :

```
% cd Path/to/library/ZendFramework
% find . -name '*.php' -not -wholename '*/Loader/Autoloader.php' \
  -not -wholename '*/Application.php' -print0 | \
  xargs -0 sed --regexp-extended --in-place 's/(require_once)/\/\/ \1/g'
```

In this command, you cans see we use 'find' for parse all php's files, and using 'sed' tool, we can change

```
require_once 'blabla.php';
```

into

```
//require_once 'blabla.php';
```

Create yours.

Hope this help